# How find data from excel sheet based on user input

Tags: php, mysql, excel

is there any way to find a particular user's id record from excel sheet.
am entering user id from a form
if anybody knows please reply
my code is below

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require_once "Classes/PHPExcel.php";
        $tmpfname = "test.xlsx";
        $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
        $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
        $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
        $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();

        echo "<table>";
        for ($row = 1; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
             echo "<tr><td>";
             echo $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
             echo "</td><td>";
             echo $worksheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue();
             echo "</td><tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";    
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clarify better what you mean with "find".

Anyway, you have already the content of the excel in the object $worksheet, so just adapting your code you can do something like:

```
$user_id_to_check="123456";
for ($row = 1; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
    // Save the user_id value from excel
    $user_id_from_excel=$worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue(); // assuming cell A store the user_id
    // compare user_id
    if ($user_id_to_check==$user_id_from_excel) {
        // OK
        } else {
        // KO
    }
}
```

Comment: this is full looping, right? any way to find that user'id record only.

Comment: what is $lastRow here?

Comment: $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); is the same, I just pasted the part I modified.

Comment: And yes, it is full looping. If you want to loop just once you would have to save the object content in an array  and then use array_search() function